# Simple registration form using Python Tkinter syntax error

Tags: python, windows, forms, tkinter, syntax-error

Hi I'm trying to run in my windows machine this code : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-simple-registration-form-using-tkinter/

So I'm having this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I'm not sure why is this happening I think it could be the route that I'm using:

```
wb = load_workbook('C:\Users\Desktop\register\excel.xlsx')
```

Maybe is missing import the os. Some help please to run it

Comment: Please don't try to use code from that web site, or learn from those tutorials. It has consistently proven to be low quality.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel could you recomend me one please?